# Angle notation for complex numbers in polar form

Tags: math-mode, typography

I am looking for suggestions on how to typeset complex numbers in the modulo-argument form, sometimes called phasor notation. Have already checked [Conventions for typesetting complex vectors and vectors with complex components](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42790/conventions-for-typesetting-complex-vectors-and-vectors-with-complex-components) but nobody mentions this in particular. I am explicitly excluding exponential and sine-cosine notations.
My MWE is as follows

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    $z = r \angle \phi$
\end{document}
```

I think it looks ugly, specially if the angle has many digits, ie

```
$z = 1.19 \angle -78.2039^{\circ}$
```

I was thinking of an `\angle` replacement which maybe would extend the lower segment up to the last digit. What do you think?

**EDIT:** It looks like the `steinmetz` package doesn't do a good job with the vertical space if the `\phasor{}` argument has a `\fraction{}{}` with parenthesis, see:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{steinmetz}

\begin{document}
    Something.
    \[I = I \phase{\left(\frac{A_0}{B_0}\right)}\]
    This line is too close to the upper equation, don't you think?

    \[I = I \phase{\left(\frac{A_0}{B_0}\right)}\]
    Whereas this line is NOT so close to the upper equation.
\end{document}
```

Strangely, commenting the first line (`% Something.`) fixes the problem. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Use \textdegree insted of \circ

Comment: @pablos: `\textdegree` seems to be working in text mode only for me. Using it inside `$...$` or `\[...\]` outputs nothing.

Comment: @Noitaenola You can use an empty line after Something.

Maybe you can try \phase[1]{\left(\frac{A_0}{B_0}\right)} that seems to "fix" it.

Comment: @Noitaenola, I guess you can try the siunitx package. So you can use, for instance, $I=10\phase{\ang{30}}$.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `steinmetz` package was written exactly for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{steinmetz}

\begin{document}

$z = 1.19 \phase{-78.2039^{\circ}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This notation looks so awesome compared to `\angle`!