# "Rare" polar form

Tags: math-mode, typography

I'm looking for ways to write this [image], similar to what the `steinmetz` package, but it must run in a `\tikzpicture` environment (via `node`) and in an  `\align` environment, for example.

Note that this form is similar but different from [Angle notation for complex numbers in polar form](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185079/angle-notation-for-complex-numbers-in-polar-form)

I tried

`\newcommand{\polar}[2]{
 \ensuremath{#1^{\,\rule[-1.1mm]{0.2mm}{3mm}\underline{\,#2{\color{white}/}}}}}`

but frankly, it looks really ugly

thank you

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{steinmetz}
\newcommand\polar[2]{#1 ^{\,\raisebox{3pt}{\scriptsize$\phase{#2^{\circ}}$}}}

\begin{document}

$z = \polar{1.19}{-78.2039}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Works fine in `align`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{steinmetz,amsmath}
\newcommand\polar[2]{#1 ^{\,\raisebox{3pt}{\scriptsize$\phase{#2^{\circ}}$}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
z_1 &= \polar{1.19}{-78.2039}\\
z_2 &= \polar{2}{33}\\
\vdots&\\
z_{10} &= \polar{4.1}{\sqrt{3}/6}\\
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

...and as a `tikz` node:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{steinmetz}
\newcommand\polar[2]{#1 ^{\,\raisebox{3pt}{\scriptsize$\phase{#2^{\circ}}$}}}

\newcommand*\rectangled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
    \node[shape=rectangle,draw,inner sep=2pt, rounded corners=4pt, thick] (char) {#1};}}

\begin{document}
  A rectangled number \rectangled{$\polar{1.19}{-78.2039}$}: No problem normally as it is used as normal charakter and TeX can set it in the right position.

\begin{sloppypar}
  A button with a longer name is marked using the same command and \rectangled{$\polar{2}{33}$} if it is set to the end of a line.
\end{sloppypar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution using an `array` environment and `siunitx`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\mypolar}[2]{\ensuremath{#1^{\,\setlength{\arraycolsep}{1pt}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.33}\begin{array}{@{}|l@{}}\scriptstyle\ang{#2}\\\hline\end{array}}}}

\begin{document}

\mypolar{5}{38.5}

\end{document}
```

[image]